# Beings who are not aware of their own existence?

Tags: sutras, mind, realms, brahma, aggregates

In some realms there are some beings who are not aware of their own existence (Some place in Brahma realm). How do their aggregates work when they themselves aren't aware of their existence?

If you can please provide a sutta, Sutra, link, or a reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In some realms there are some beings who are not aware of their own existence (Some place in Brahma realm). How do their aggregates work when they themselves aren't aware of their existence?

Unconscious beings ([asannasatta](http://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/ay/asannasatta.htm)) has consciousness suppressed temporarily until their life span ends. Due to this they cannot be aware of anything including themselves.

Also interestingly the Abhidhamma says this is the only plane where animals do not cling to life or have the love of life or attachment to the plane of birth.

In the Arupa Loka consciousness is present hence the mind works which means there can be self awareness.

> If you can please provide a sutta, Sutra, link, or a reference.

[Sutta references to unconscious beings.](https://suttacentral.net/search?query=asa%C3%B1%C3%B1asatta)

Comment: thank you very much for the link. I am going to use it in my blogs too.